# Plot not showing up in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dirichlet

How can I fix the following code

```
alpha <- 1
draws <- 15
dimen <- 10
require(MCMCpack)
x <- rdirichlet(draws, rep(alpha, dimen))
require(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(item=factor(rep(1:10,15)), 
             draw=factor(rep(1:15,each=10)), 
             value=as.vector(t(x)))
ggplot(dat,aes(x=item,y=value,ymin=0,ymax=value)) +
       geom_point(colour=I("blue"))       + 
       geom_linerange(colour=I("blue"))   + 
       facet_wrap(~draw,ncol=5)           + 
       scale_y_continuous(lim=c(0,1))     +
       opts(panel.border=theme_rect())
```

to not to get this empty plot:

[image: empty Dirichlet plot]

Comment: How sure are you that all of your `value` values are between 0 and 1?

Comment: @Henrik: `library(ggplot2); library(MCMCpack)`

Comment: @Henrik:Sorry, I added Libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you get the following error message:

```
'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)
theme_rect is deprecated. Use 'element_rect' instead. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.1)
```

If so, this should be stated in your question.

Using the current version of ggplot2 (0.9.3.1) and `theme()` instead of `opts()`, this script:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = item, y = value, ymin = 0, ymax = value)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") + 
  geom_linerange(colour = "blue") + 
  facet_wrap(~draw, ncol = 5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(lim = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

...gives this plot:

[image]

Is this what you want?

You may also wish to check the `scales` argument in `?facet_wrap`, and `coord_cartesian` as an alternative to set limits in `scale_y_continuous`

Comment: Awesome! Sorry thought that the "Deprecated..." message would not make any changes and is just a suggestion like Java crossed functions.

Comment: I tend to think it is safest to always run the latest version of packages (and R) and use current, 'non-deprecated' syntax. Then you can at least rule out such factors as a cause of a problem.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I'll try to do so.